# Why is the equation $\frac{(z-i)^2}{(z^2+1)^2}=\frac{1}{(z+i)^2} $ in the residue theorem accurate?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, residue-calculus

I don't understand the reasoning here:

[image]

$\frac{(z-i)^2}{(z^2+1)^2}=\frac{1}{(z+i)^2} $

Comment: This writing can be seen from outer space. :-$)$

Answer (score 1):

Well, $z² + 1 = (z-i)(z+i)$. As the latter is squared in the denominator, you can cancel out $(z-i)^2$.

Comment: Oh man, you stare at something for a while and oversee the obvious, thanks.